# Minecraft downloads stuff to previous location after I moved it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I moved .minecraft to a different folder, in the launch options, I put in the new location, but it still downloads files to the previous location. This is the log:

Unable to save download. realms-1.13.7.jar
Name: realms-1.13.7.jar
URL: https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/mojang/realms/1.13.7/realms-1.13.7.jar
Error details: Attempting to move successful download to C:/Users\hrovn\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\libraries\com/mojang/realms/1.13.7/realms-1.13.7.jar
There is not enough space on the disk
Filename on disk: ba62-32ec-4fc9-cf41
Path: D:\TEMP\ba62-32ec-4fc9-cf41
Exists: file

My new location is D:/all items\games.minecraft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files for the launcher, like versions, launch configurations, libraries, etc. are always in the default location. Only the files for the game itself, like worlds, resource packs, logs, etc. are in the chosen game directory.

Your error message comes from having not enough space on your D: drive. Free up some space to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, but I literally can't clear up any space. Also, It's my C: drive thats full.

Comment: You need a bit of free space in your C: drive, otherwise all programs will give you error messages. Believe me, I filled my C: drive to 100.00% once and everything broke. Try reinstalling programs on a different drive, look in all the folders (including program folders) what takes up much space, etc. I recommend WinDirStat to look for big piles of needlessly filled up memory. And you can google "how to free up hard drive space" or something like that.